# Fetch as Google huge margin on top and bottom

Tags: seo, google-search-console, css, javascript

My website has recently started dropping in Google rankings so I started checking out Webmaster Tools.

Weird thing is when I used Fetch as Google with render, I noticed huge margins on the top and bottom of the preview (see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaAiOZnlg6Y).

On Google render my main content is not above the fold, is this something I should be worried about? If so, do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I see what you mean. Unfortunately, I have no idea what is causing the problem. I would try and fix this. It could be an indication. For the record, it shows up fine in Chrome so I would have thought Fetch and Render would be the same. Sorry. Cheers!!

Comment: Please edit the question to include a screenshot instead of a link to a YouTube video.

Comment: Is any of your CSS or JavaScript blocked in robots.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. "Hero" section was resized to viewport size with JavaScript:

```
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $(".cover,.heightblock").css('min-height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();

 $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
```

This works fine on both desktop and mobile devices. The problem is Googlebot (or just Fetch as Google feature) has incredible **3454px** viewport size.

I've abandoned resizing to viewport via JavaScript.